# WooCommerce out of stock issue inspite of product shows in stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've stuck in wooCommerce out of stock issue in-spite of product in stock. On archive page product shows out of stock but when I open in single product page then products show in stock. Only some products shows out of stock label on archive page.

I am using variable products, means each product has different variations. I tried to resolve this issue by increasing product variation limit but no results found. Facing to much problem, some time it resolve when I update my stock through wp all import plugin but after some day again shows out of stock label, Kindly help me out.

here is the code for increasing variation limit which I've tried on function.php file.

```
    define( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 150 );
```

Comment: There is a known issue with importing products and variable stock levels, for variants which are out of stock you should mark your stock level as null rather than 0. This should solve your issue

Comment: p.s. see Zachs answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639288/woocommerce-products-showing-out-of-stock-message-when-not-actually-out-of-sto